# About execute "sudo python3 program" at ubuntu 1604

Tags: sudo, gui

I have a python program needs to get the information from smartctl, 
it means the program executes as the title.
But the QT interface looks like a change to a native interface
How do I solve this problem?

Thanks,
Stephen

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is wrong with [GSmartControl](https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/Screenshots)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `smartctl` with `subprocess.Popen()`  and nothing else needs `sudo` privilege except `subprocess.Popen()` you can just add `sudo` to that part. For example,

```
subprocess.Popen(['sudo','smartctl','-i','/dev/sda'])
```

Since you're mentioning Qt in your question, you probably want to save user's password via a dialog and [pass the password to subprocess via stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument). For instance,

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','-S','smartctl','-i','/dev/sda',stdin=subprocess.PIPE])
smartctl_output  = proc.communicate(input=user_password_variable)
```

---

Depending on your purpose, you also might consider [adding your username to `disk` group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35949779/3701431) so that you shouldn't need to use `sudo` with `smartctl` at all

Comment: `pkexec` might be better here. It should show a graphical prompt  for password.

Comment: @Olorin True. I sort of stopped suggesting it, since for some reason `pkexec` has to be configured and some people here don't like it. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyyfor basic use cases it seems to be autoconfigured in 18.04, probably in earlier versions too but for sure i assume in following versions.